# ordernar lista por tamanho de palavras usando bubblesort

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando usar o bubble sort para arrumar uma lista de string em ordem decrescente, mas só estou conseguindo fazer pra arrumar por ordem alfabética. Alguém saberia me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
arq_palavras = open('exer_1.txt', 'r')

linhas = arq_palavras.read().lower()
lista_linhas = linhas.split()
print(lista_linhas)

for i in range(len(lista_linhas)-1):
        for j in range(len(lista_linhas) -1 -i):
            if lista_linhas[j] > lista_linhas[j + 1]:
                aux = lista_linhas[j]
                lista_linhas[j] = lista_linhas[j + 1]
                lista_linhas[j + 1] = aux

print(lista_linhas)
arq_palavras.close()
```

o arquivo no caso tem as seguintes string:

```
Top Coder comp Wedn at midnight
one three five
I love cpp C
sj sa df r e w f d s v c x z sd fd a
```

e o output desejado seria esse, com todas as letras minusculas, e caso as strings tenham a mesma quantidade de letras, colocar então em ordem alfabética:

```
midnight coder comp wedn top at 
three five one 
love cpp c i 
df fd sa sd sj a c d e f r s v w x z
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uma possível solução para o seu problema.

```py
arq_palavras = open('exer_1.txt', 'r')

linhas = arq_palavras.read().lower().split('\n')

for i in range(len(linhas)):
  linha = linhas[i].split()
  for j in range(len(linha) - 1):
    for k in range(len(linha) - 1 - j):
      if len(linha[k]) < len(linha[k + 1]):
        aux = linha[k]
        linha[k] = linha[k + 1]
        linha[k + 1] = aux
      elif (len(linha[k]) == len(linha[k + 1])) and (linha[k] > linha[k + 1]):
        aux = linha[k]
        linha[k] = linha[k + 1]
        linha[k + 1] = aux
  linhas[i] = " ".join(linha)

print(linhas)
arq_palavras.close()
```